# Calling another method to another class

Tags: python, class, methods

i newbie on python programming, i so confused, why i cant call another method from another class,

this is my source- file : 8_turunan lanjut.py

```
class Karyawan(object):
'untuk kelas karyawan'
jml_karyawan = 0  # Class variable

# constructor
def __init__(self, kid, nama, jabatan):
    self.kid = kid
    self.nama = nama
    self.jabatan = jabatan
    Karyawan.jml_karyawan += 1


# method
def infoKaryawan(self):
    print "Karyawan baru masuk"
    print "==================="
    print "ID : %s " % self.kid
    print "Nama : %s " % self.nama
    print "Jabatan : %s " % self.jabatan
```

second source file : 9_turunan advance.py

```
    # cara mengakses/memakai class/membuat Object
class cobaa():
    obj = Karyawan("K001", "Ganjar", "Teknisi")
    obj.infoKaryawan()
    # tambah karyawan baru
    obj2 = Karyawan("K002", "Nadya", "Akunting")
    obj2.infoKaryawan()

    # tampilkan total Karyawan
print "-----------------------------"
print "Total Karyawan : %d " % Karyawan.jml_karyawan
```

how can i call method **init** and infoKaryawan to class cobaa on file 9_turunan advance.py

i already put `from percobaan.Karyawan import __init__` on file : 9_turunan advance and its wrong, i dont know where's the problem of my source

here my directory sturcture
[directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anIXs.png)

Comment: You should not put spaces in your python files or package names

Comment: hmmm, i am newbie on python mate..can you tell me the reason why i shouldnt put space on my files/packages?
because my IDE (pyCharm Community) its support to put space, then i try...
and 1 more things, why the space(4 space above line class declaration) its so affect,
no offsense i just asking something my experience mate :)

Comment: Spaces cause a problem when you import. I'm not talking about spacing within the content of the files. That's just Python style guidelines called PEP 8

Comment: ah i see, okay thanks so much mate for the information :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your indentation is off in your class.  It should read as follows:

```
class Karyawan(object):
    'untuk kelas karyawan'
    jml_karyawan = 0  # Class variable

    def __init__(self, kid, nama, jabatan):
        self.kid = kid
        self.nama = nama
        self.jabatan = jabatan
        Karyawan.jml_karyawan += 1

    def infoKaryawan(self):
        print "Karyawan baru masuk"
        print "==================="
        print "ID : %s " % self.kid
        print "Nama : %s " % self.nama
        print "Jabatan : %s " % self.jabatan
```

Then, in your other file, just import it as such: `from filename import Karyawan`

Good luck!

Comment: my identation is on mate, i just know that file name cant be numeric at first words
but thanks for **from filename import Karyawan**

its right :)

Comment: Ah ok, no worries then.  Your formatting in your question really threw me off as it could cause the conditions you were asking about.  Nevertheless, glad it worked out.